# IIS 7.x - Alias creation restart AppDomain

Tags: iis-7.5

We are working on IIS 7.x - we have site named `www.lms.com` (example). we have SAAS model based system and sell it to multiple client.

e.g. C1, C2 & C3 are client and they all have same source code but they have following URL

```
Client C1 has URL http://C1.lms.com 
Client C2 has URL http://C2.lms.com
```

When we create Client in the System we create aliasing entry in the IIS Programatically through our Application. Note, we have already `"*"` alias entry in the IIS already done.

When we add new Alias our Application Domain Restarts (though same Application if we run on the IIS 6.0 - works without any issue or AppDomain restart).

Please suggest how to allow alias entry on IIS 7.x without restarting IIS OR AppDomain.

Any help on the same appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before and there doesn't appear to be a way around it. I'm guessing this is because you're adding a new endpoint which the app domain needs to be hooked into at some deeper level and it only does this at App Domain initialisation time.

The work around may be to have separate sites for each SAAS site and point them all at the same web folder.

This is probably preferable because you'll have more fine grained control over each SAAS site's resources and you can stop one site without it affecting the others.